# Covariance of two random variables with monotone transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose I know that, for two random variables $X,Y$, we have 
$$Cov(X,Y)\neq 0.$$
What happens if we take a monotone transformation of $X$; will the inequality persist? That is, say $f(.)$ is a strictly increasing (not necessarily linear) function, then does it follow that 
$$Cov(f(X),Y)\neq 0?$$
Since covariance depicts linear relationships, this would only follow if $f$ were linear, right? In that case, under which assumptions on the relation of $X,Y$ can we say that it does follow for nonlinear transformations $f$? (If it helps, I am currently looking at the case where $f$ is the cdf of the standard normal $\Phi$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I have edited the question changing $f$ to $g$ in order to keep the symbol $f$ for probability density functions).*
First, indeed, when the transformation is linear(affine actually), the covariance involving the transformation will continue to be non-zero. For non-linear transformations you cannot obtain very specific conditions. My approach is the following:

For compactness, set $Z=g\left(X\right)$. Then you require the conditions under which
$$\operatorname{Cov}(Z,Y)\neq 0? \;\Rightarrow\; E\left(ZY\right)\,-\,E\left(Z\right)E\left(Y\right)\, \neq0?\qquad [1]$$

Using Integrals to express the expected values, we require (assuming certain regularity conditions) $$\int_{D_Z} \int_{D_Y} zyf_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right)\,dy\,dz \;-\;\left(\int_{D_Z}zf_{Z}\left(z\right)dz\right) \left(\int_{D_Y} yf_{Y}\left(y\right)\,dy\right)\neq0?$$

$$\Rightarrow \int_{D_Z} \int_{D_Y} zyf_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right)\,dy\,dz \;-\;\int_{D_Z} \int_{D_Y} zyf_{Z}\left(z\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\,dy\,dz\neq0?$$

$$\Rightarrow \int_{D_Z} \int_{D_Y} zy\left[f_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right) \;-\;f_{Z}\left(z\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\right]\,dy\,dz\neq0?\qquad[2]$$

where the $f()$ functions are joint or marginal probability density functions, and $D$ denotes the support. Now define $\omega \equiv(z,y)$ and note that $zy\;$,$\,z\;$,$\;y\;$, can all be derived as linear transformations of $\omega$, say $zy=\tau_0(\omega)\;$,$\,z=\tau_1(\omega)\;$,$\;y=\tau_2(\omega)\;$. For example $z=\omega[1\; 0]'$, the prime denoting the transpose. Also define $C\equiv D_Z\times D_Y$. Then we can compact even further by writing
$$\cdots\Rightarrow \int_C h\left[\omega,\tau_0(\omega),\tau_1(\omega),\tau_2(\omega)\right]d\omega\neq0?\qquad[3]$$

Why all this trouble? Because now it is clear that what you are asking is the requirements under which a double definite integral of a function of its variable does *not* equal zero when integrated over the whole domain of its variable. Reversely, we want to exclude the conditions under which this integral equals zero.
First since $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)\neq 0\;$, it implies that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Therefore we have $f_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right) \;\neq\;f_X \left(x\right)f_Y \left(y\right)$ . But this does not guarantee that the double integral will be non-zero. It may still equal zero if the integrand in eq.[2] is an *odd function*  w.r.t. to at least one of $z$ or $y$, and if the domain w.r.t to this variable is symmetric around the origin (which will hold if for example $D=  \Bbb R$ - extended). Assume that indeed $C=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ extended. Therefore we must guarantee that the integrand 
$zy\left[f_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right) \;-\;f_{Z}\left(z\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\right]$
is not an odd function w.r.t. to either $z$ or $y$ *separately*.  Now if you work the integrand, substituting $-z$ for $z$ etc, you will be able to reduce the condition into the following: **"The non-linear transformation should not be such as to make *both* $f_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right) \;$ *and* $f_{Z}\left(z\right)$ even functions of $z$."**
For $Y$ this could be stated as **"If the pdf of $Y$ is an even function, then the non-linear transformation should not be such as to make  $f_{Z,Y}\left(z,y\right) \;$ an even function of $y$."**.  Obviously this is distribution-specific (or at least distribution family- specific) and you cannot go more specific than that. If it looks disappointingly general, imagine a true jungle. Then independence is a straight clear path through this jungle, and linear dependence is an elliptical clear path approaching asymptotically the straight path of independence. The rest of the jungle is non-linear dependence.
$$ \text{}$$
***Afterthought:*** A less "mathematical" and more "statistical" condition (although not necessarily more useful) would be *"The non-linear transformation must be such as to not render the variables $Z$ and $Y$ [sub-independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subindependence)"*. In a nutshell, sub-independent random variables are dependent but uncorrelated: their dependence is "perfectly non-linear".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see how the integrand in [2] being an odd function will make the covariance zero if we integrate over the reals. If I rewrite [2] for the odd $z$ part: $$\int_{-\infty}^0 f_{Z,Y}(z)-f_Z(z)f_y(z) dz+\int_{0}^\infty f_{Z,Y}(z)-f_Z(z)f_Y(z) dz$$ so $$\Leftrightarrow \int_0^\infty f_{Z,Y}(-z)-f_Z(-z)f_y(-z) +f_{Z,Y}(z)-f_Z(z)f_Y(z) dz\neq0.$$ But that means the transformation should not make both $f_{Z,Y}$ and $f_Z$ an odd function of $Z$, right? You write it should not make them an even function.

Comment: Don't forget the "z" outside the brackets!

Comment: Yes, you're right, they have to be even functions. But am I right that if both $X,Y$ are positive, then the "even function condition" is not applicable?
Both of you provided sufficient conditions and I tossed a virtual coin to determine who gets the accept. You won.

Comment: Luck is always welcome, although not chased. Indeed, the property of "evenness" or "oddness" can only be defined for functions whose domain includes both positive and negative values. If $X,Y$ have positive range => the domain of the densities will be only in the positive orthant.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\ne0$ and consider some increasing function $g$ (you say that the case of interest is when $g=\Phi$ the standard normal CDF, which is increasing). The question is to find some conditions on $(X,Y)$ implying that $\mathrm{Cov}(g(X),Y)\ne0$, presumably for every such $g$.

Here is a sufficient condition: one knows that $E[Y\mid X]=h(X)$ for some function $h$ depending only on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Then:

> If $h$ is increasing or if $h$ is decreasing, then $\mathrm{Cov}(g(X),Y)\ne0$.

To prove this, assume without loss of generality that $h$ is increasing, note that $\mathrm{Cov}(g(X),Y)$ is also $\mathrm{Cov}(g(X),h(X))=E[g(X)h(X)]-E[g(X)]E[h(X)]$, and that for nondecreasing functions $g$ and $h$, $E[g(X)h(X)]\geqslant E[g(X)]E[h(X)]$ with equality if and only if $g$ or $h$ is almost surely constant on $D$ such that $P[X\in D]=1$. Here $g$ and $h$ are increasing everywhere hence $E[g(X)h(X)]\gt E[g(X)]E[h(X)]$ except if $X$ is almost surely constant but then $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ hence this does not happen and the claim is proved.

Of course, the partial result above is only useful when one can compute $E[Y\mid X]=h(X)$ easily. Here are two remarks in this direction. First, when $(X,Y)$ has a density,
$$
h(x)=f_X(x)^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\mathrm dy,
$$
hence one should be able to check the monotony of $h$ in some specific situations.
Second, when $(X,Y)$ is normal, $h(x)=ax+b$ where $a=\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\sqrt{\mathrm{var}(Y)/\mathrm{var}(X)}$ hence $h$ is increasing if and only if $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\gt0$.