# Stochastic independence vs. linear independence

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm revising for my statistics exam and I came across a remark that two events can be stochasticly dependent but linearly independent (uncorrelated).

So this means $P(X=x \cap Y=y) \neq P(X=x)\cdot P(Y=y) $, but $\operatorname{cov}(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow \mu(x,y)=\mu(x)\mu(y)$. How can it be, given that $\mu$ is calculated from $P$ as $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i P(X=x_i)$. Is there any simple numeric example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of the simplest examples.  Let $X=-1,0,\text{ or }1$, each with probability $1/3$.  Then the covariance between $X$ and $X^2$ is $0$.

(But the term "linear independence" in mathematics usually means something other than that.)

Comment: thanks... i know, linar independece is usually defined for vectors... so, is there any better expression for cov(x,y)=0?

Comment: @smihael : One might say "independence versus uncorrelatedness".

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350971/covariance-of-two-random-variables-with-monotone-transformation/455129#455129)