# Covariance of functions of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

It is general known that if $X$ is a random variable, then for increasing functions $f,g$ we have that $Cov(f(X),g(X))\ge 0$.

I am trying to investigate a more specific result for joint,y distributed random variables. If $(X,Y)$ is a 2d normal distribution with $Cov(X,Y)\ge 0$, and if $f,g$ are now two different increasing functions does it necessarily hold that $Cov(f(X),g(Y))\ge 0$?

Comment: Are f and g increasing for your question?

Comment: Yes, f,g are increasing (but need not be the same)

Comment: if the claim is false, then I am curious if $f=g$ makes it true. I doubt this however as only increasing was used in the first remake I mentioned.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ random variables?

Comment: Increasing functions, sorry fixed.

Comment: Sorry I also missed a very obvious assumption that is needed to apply the remark. It is that the components of the normal are positively correlated

Comment: [Somewhat related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350971/covariance-of-two-random-variables-with-monotone-transformation?rq=1)